# Rails routing to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

When setting up the root route, is there any compelling reason to choose this syntax:

```
map.root :controller => "login", :action => 'show'
```

over this syntax:

```
match "/" => "login#show"
```

The second syntax will allow you to use the `:constraints` option, where the first wont.  Is there any reason to use the first option?

Comment: Answer would depend on your version of Rails. what `providence` answered works for Rails 3...

Comment: hmm, yes it does seem that I'm mixing rails 2 and rails 3.  `map.*` works in rails 3, but it's not the preferred method

Comment: Why would you need to use `constraints` for the root path? AFAIK, the root route is just that: "/" ... anything else should match another defined route.

Comment: I want different subdomains to have different roots.

Comment: @DanCheail you might want to use constraints on the root path to have different root routes based on the domain/subdomain like mentioned on http://stackoverflow.com/a/6058737/137067

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `root :to` rails 3 automatically creates the helper methods root_url and root_path for referencing your application root.  These methods are often used in gems to reference your applications root and I'm not actually sure where these would point or if they would even work if you don't specify anything (never tried it).  Plus it's the ["rails way" of doing things](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) so it's usually best to follow unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 2):

I believe root routes should be set up as follows:

```
root :to => "Something#index"
```

The methods you suggested sound like they may cause conflicts later on down the road.

Comment: Ah, a third syntax, this one allows you to use `:constraints`.  Same question applies, any reason to do this over `match '/'`

Comment: I'm rather new to rails myself, so don't take my answer as absolute, but all I can think of is if there is ever another reference to '/', you would get directed to login#show. Additionally, if someone is already signed in, you don't want them to be directed to the login page, really. I'd set a root route to some more useful page, then force rails to check if the user is authenticated before displaying the useful page. If they aren't then redirect to the login#show. Note: I'm assuming login#show is a login page, not another page just named login.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4, here's a quicker code you can use:

```
 root 'login#new_session'
```

You can substitute new_session with show/index/etc, just make sure to define it in your login controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following two are the same:

```
root :to => 'login#show'

match '/' => 'login#show', :as => :root
```

Just like other paths, if you want a `root_path`, then for the `match '/'`, you have to specify it by yourself.

So I think they just do the same thing (routing you to `login#show` if the path is `/`), but the first one would have more semantic meaning.