# Rails 3 routing and multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app allows people to create portfolios. I would like for them to be able to connect their domain to their portfolio.

So somedomain.com would show /portfolio/12, someotherdomain.com would show /portfolio/13 and so on. But I don't want the redirect. I want the user to see somedomain.com in the browser url.

How do I do that?

Ok, I've found this solution:

```
match "/" => "portfolio#show", 
  :constraints => { :domain => "somedomain.com" }, 
  :defaults => { :id => '1' }
```

As I don't have many custom domains, this is fine for now but the question is - how to make this dynamic, to read domain and id data from db?

Comment: Routes are parsed only once at application startup. So you would have to monkey patch your Rails to accept ruby `Proc` in the defaults which then would return correct id from DB, based on incoming `request`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should add a field to the portfolio model to hold the user's domain. Make sure this field is unique. Adding an index to the field in your database would also be wise.

Second, set your root to route to the `portfolios#show` action, as you already did, but without the constraints.

Then, in the `PortfoliosController#show` method, do the following check:

```
if params[:id]
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
else
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find_by_domain(request.host)
end
```

After this, the only thing left to do is to make sure your own domain does not trigger the `portfolio#show` action. This can be done with the constraint you used before, but now with your own domain. Be sure to put this line in routes.rb above the line for the `portfolio#show` action, since the priority is based upon order of creation.

Answer (score 34):

Ok, let's assume you own `yourdomain.com` and use it as your home page for your application. And any other domain name like `somedomain.net` is mapped to a portfolio page.

First of all, in your `routes.rb` you need to catch `yourdomain.com` and map it to wherever your home page is, so that it stands out from the rest of the crowd.

```
root :to => "static#home", :constraints => { :domain => "yourdomain.com" }
```

Then you need to catch any other root on any domain and forward it to your `PortfoliosController`

```
root :to => "portfolios#show"
```

Keep in mind that this line will only be checked if the previous line fails to match.

Then in your `PortfoliosController` find the requested portfolio by its domain rather than id.

```
def show
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find_by_domain(request.host)
  …
end
```

Of course you may want to rescue from an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception in case the domain is not in your database, but let's leave that for another discussion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! BTW, if you allow `:edit/:update` actions for the domains too (e.g. let the portfolio owner change it), consider using `before_filter` to aquire the id and place it in the `param` hash.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess this is basically the same solution as Kris suggested.

Comment: just a hint: if you are dealing with subdomains like `admin.yourdomain.com` and `callcenter.yourdomain.com`, you can simply exchange `{ :domain => 'yourdomain.com' }` to `{ :subdomain => 'admin' }`. And you can also differentiate the port with: `{ :subdomain => 'admin', :port => 443 }` .

And please don't use hash rockets anymore ;-)

Comment: doesn't work for later rails versions, multiple routes for root are not permitted: "Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'" unless you use as: to differentiate the routes, for example as: :route1 and as: :route2

Comment: AFAIK this works with Rails 4 as well. No idea about 5+. @jpw any idea on when this stopped working?

Comment: no idea, I jumped from 4 to 6. but adding the as: to rename one of the routes worked under rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

The `request` object seems not to be available to the `routes.rb` file w/o some patching.

There are some plugins that make it available, but most of them seem to be outdated. This one here [request_routing](https://github.com/jamesbebbington/request_routing) seems to be with the latest commit dates so it would be most up to date. Though I doubt it will work with Rails 3.0 out of the box, it is a start and might not be that hard to port.

Answer (score -3):

Your users can set DNS CNAME redirects so that requests for `theirdomain.com` land on `your_app.com/portfolio/12`.

Comment: You can't do CNAMEs that point to full URL. CNAMEs only apply to domain part of the URL. What you imply would be a redirect commonly provided by DNS providers, which are not what the Peter wants.

Comment: @Laas Thanks for correcting me. Perhaps this kind of thing (DNS redirects) would work with subdomains, but that's also not what Peter wants.

Comment: There actually is no such thing as DNS redirect. What is served under this name is (1) point domain to service provider's host and (2) that host has a webserver that accepts this domain and answers all requests with `HTTP 3XX` (redirect) response.