# Deploying subdomains from Roots in Rails app while running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am working with adding subdomains in my Rails app for different blogs hosted on the site (example.blogthing.com vs example2.blogthing.com). This site is being hosted on Heroku.

Now, I found this [answer on how to set up subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054668/rails-3-routing-and-multiple-domains/6058737#6058737) routing, and it is working locally like so in my Roots file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments

  root :to => "pages#home", :constraints => { :domain => "blogthing.com" }, as: nil
  root :to => "setup#index"
```

Now that it's deployed to Heroku, I am noticing an issue. When I go to the root domain, it routes correctly to home. When I add any subdomain on it, the browser shows an error that this site can't be reached.

Is there a problem with the very simple strategy outlined above that would need to be implemented differently to work with Heroku?

I should also note that I have my DNS of my customer domain targeting my Heroku site - so I am trying this with a real .dom domain, just putting my `example1.` in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few days of troubleshooting, I want to clear this up in case in anyone needs this question in the future.

If you are running a Rails app with a custom domain on Heroku, there are necessary steps both **in Heroku** but also for wherever your domain is hosted. Here are my steps, and it is working successfully now.

First, create a record of the custom domain in Heroku. I did this from the command line by running `heroku domains:add www.blog.example.com` or whatever. This now gives us a custom domain to point to from our DNS.

Second, we need to have a record created on the domain host to point to this subdomain. I use Google Domains and did this by going to Settings > Custom Resources and creating a new resource for `www.blog.` to match by Heroku record.

This now exists on both sides, so the last step is allowing the app to route correctly. In my `Roots.rb` file, I found [this guide](https://gist.github.com/bsodmike/1369419) and adapted it to use `get` instead of `match` for Rails 4:

```
 get '/' => 'blog#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'www.blog' }  
 root :to => "pages#home"
```

And with that, I deployed to Heroku and it works using that constraint. Hope that helps.